# How to write a test to cover a bugfix of a segfault

Tags: unit-testing

There was a bug that I recently fixed that was causing a segmentation fault (due to an out-of-bounds access).  The maintainer of the project is asking me to write a unit test to cover the bugfix.

How can I do this?  The bug exhibited undefined behavior, so even if my test passed, it's not proof of anything.  Should I use a loop to test it 100 times to make the test more likely to catch a regression?

Comment: Can you provide more information? (1) language? (2) nature of the out-of-bounds access - is it a static-size array, dynamically allocated array, or non-array invalid pointer access? Is it a lifetime (use-after-free) issue?

Comment: Another question: (3) is it multi-threaded, and is the bug related to multi-threading?

Comment: @rwong, I was trying to keep the question general so it would be of benefit to a wider audience.  But I'm fixing a bug in Cython code (in the package called Pandas).  It's a dynamically allocated C array and it was being accessed during its lifetime `my_array[-1]`.

Comment: Garrett: Here is a resolution specific to your piece of code. (It is not widely-applicable at all; just specific to this one code example.) When attempting to access the last item of an array, it is helpful to be reminded that this access will fail *if and only if* the array itself has zero size. (Think about it.) Therefore, to prevent failure of code that depends on the value of the last item of an array, one should first check the array itself is not empty, and then proceed to load the last item's value. If you study the code generated for every kind of language, you will see this logic.

Comment: Therefore, the first step to solving this issue is: think about what should this function do when the array is empty?

Comment: Is it possible to use something like `@cython.boundscheck(not debug)`? Or perhaps rather a `@cython.boundscheck(optimize_boundscheck)` which only set in debug builds?

Comment: A search by question title returns this: [When and how does cython do boundscheck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263757/when-and-how-does-cython-do-boundscheck) and the answer is not very comforting.

Comment: you can use DUMA or Electric Fence for ensuring that out of bounds accesses in C/C++ will generate a segfault. You can then use your favorite testing tools with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most pragmatic approach is IMHO by not blindly sticking to the model of "not changing the project's code under any circumstances."  So my suggestion is: **make the code testable first** - change the project's code slightly to make sure the out-of-bounds access leads to a reproducible and catchable error. Note that making code testable is very often a prerequisition for any kind of test automation.

That modification might be some kind of out-of-bounds assertion, using the kind of error-signaling your team normally uses inside your project (an error code, throwing an exception, calling a signal, or whatelse you prefer), but it should allow your automatic test to detect the error condition. Note further that this change is not the same "fixing the bug" - the bugfix should probably lead to code which doesn't create that out-of-bounds condition any more.

Then you should apply that change to the original code *before* the bug fix was applied (if you are lucky, your VCS system will help you to revert the order in which the changes are applied). Finally you can do exactly what Robert Harvey wrote - write a test which causes the error to appear, and run the test *after* you made the code testable, once before and once after the bugfix.

Comment: It seems the maintainer won't want an out-of-bounds assertion since it's in a very performance-critical part of the code.  In fact, it's Cython code and bounds-checking was explicitly disabled.  If you're curious, here's [the line](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/0ad0e0c67652e64fa081bcb75d468e4e69f9b98f/pandas/src/generated.pyx#L9113) which has an access like `bins[-1]`.  I'm adding an if statement to return from the function upon the index being -1 (which is a valid input)...

Comment: @Garrett: activate the bounds check during testing (or at least during your specific unit test), and deactivate it in production. I am pretty sure you do not have the requirement of running a single unit test with fully optimized code.

Comment: @Garrett: having a look into the code, it looks all the "boundscheck" are disabled **blindly** throughout the whole code, hardcoded. And now as this strikes back on you, and you get hard-to-detect bugs, your teams tries to compensate that by additional test automation? That is pretty insane. IMHO "no bounds-checks" optimization should be applied only with care for the functions which really need it it. At least thing you should make the bounds-check a switchable parameter, and switch it on during test and debugging, for the whole program.

Comment: With regard to performance, one should also keep in mind "relative overhead". For example, if the function performs 1000 clock cycles of useful work, and an additional 10 cycles of error-preventive work, then the preventive work is measured at 1 percent of the useful work. (This assumes the 1000 cycles of useful work is already optimal, i.e. can't be made faster.) Performance improvements within 1 percent is less than one-tenth of the typical CPU thermal throttling/boosting fluctuations.

Comment: @rwong: absolutely. Looking a little bit deeper into the function in stake I can imagine why it might makes sense to deactivate the bounds checks: not because of the line that crashed, but because of the two levels deep nested for loops after that line. IMHO *that* part should be refactored out into a separate function, and one *might* consider to deactivate the bounds check **only for that performance critical part**, and not in general.

Comment: @Garrett: Given the surrounding functions, I would advise to factor the line that causes the crash into a separate function with bounds-checking enabled. That line occurs about half a dozen times.

Answer (score 4):

(1)

There is a concept of a ["death test"](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#How_to_Write_a_Death_Test), in which a failing piece of code would cause a process termination.

In order to execute such death test, the test harness need to start a separate process which will execute the piece of code. The termination condition is then taken as the pass or fail criteria.

Obviously, not every unit testing framework supports this kind of tests.

---

(2)

Some C++ compilers provide switches that will insert additional checks into the generated code.

Examples of what these switches will do:

1. Ensure that when the function call returns, its return address has the same value (on the stack) as when the function call was just entered.
2. Ensure that dynamically allocated memory buffers were not being overwritten before its start or after its end.

---

(3)

Finally there are also code coverage and instrumentation tools such as valgrind.

If there exists some data patterns that will reliably causes a crash (but just that you don't know which one), fuzzing can be a very effective strategy for discovering such crash-causing data patterns. E.g. [afl-fuzz](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/).

If using additional tools is out-of-question, perhaps you can modify the code yourself to make it more "testable". An example is to replace array accesses with a C++ operator overload that performs array index bounds check. The details depend on the type of code being questioned.

Answer (score 2):

Write a test that reliably reproduces the segfault in the original code first.  You should be able to duplicate the segfault by writing a test that causes the out of bound access that you fixed.  You can use the same test to demonstrate that the out-of-bound access no longer occurs in the new code.

Comment: But out-of-bounds accesses cause segfaults at random, right?  And I'm guessing that even if I can get it to reliably segfault on my machine, that may not mean it segfaults reliably on a different machine.

Comment: @Garrett Perhaps I try to define what "reliably" means. In your situation, the code reliably *attempts to read* from array index -1, whenever the array is empty. What happens after that attempt is undefined. Actually, one familiar with low-level memory management (at the level of C Standard Library) and the operating system will be able to list several possible outcomes, ranging from getting garbage, to hitting a page fault. (It might also have other consequences, such as causing a non-mapped page to become mapped.) Each OS and C Library implementation has some additional help you can use.

Answer (score 1):

If your language supports bounds checks, activate them for testing. That's certainly the easiest and the safest way to do this. As someone suggested in the comments, why not declare `@cython.boundscheck(isDebug)` where isDebug is defined at the beginning of the module (I've never worked with cython, so I'm not sure it's that easy)

That said, there are cases when you can't just activate bounds checks (example: you're using a low-level library like LAPACK or IPP that just takes a buffer and expects it to be the right size). The only way I'm aware of to guarantee access violations here is to use low-level operating system functions to allocate memory in such a way that the address immediately before (or after) the allocated block is read and write protected. On windows, `VirtualAlloc`, `VirtualProtect` and friends let you do things like that. It wastes a lot of memory and you can only protect the space before *or* after the block (unless the size of the buffer is a multiple of a memory page size). But to find hard-to-reproduce out of bounds memory access errors, it's sometimes worth all that.